# How can I create a FASTQ sequence file?

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq

I have a genomic database, which contains a simple character sequence (like `>chr1 AGTGTCA.....`). Now, I want to convert it to the standard [FASTQ format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) like this:

```
@HWUSI-EAS594-R:1:3:1453:1350#0/1 
CCCAGTTCCGACGATCGATTTGCACGTCAGAATCGCTACGGACCTCCATCAGGGTTTCCCCTGACTTCGTCCTGACCAGG
+   
ea^cdfdffgggggggggggeggggdggdffgdbdgddgggg`g^dfbfgdggcfbgfffcb]gffbfcfcefbbBBBB
```

As I have no clear idea about this type of format, I am not able to convert it.  How can I convert a simple character sequence to the FASTQ format (as in the above example)?

Specifically, I am asking:

1. Is there any existing code to do the encoding?
2. If not, how can I encode the character sequence in FASTQ? What does this format imply and how can I create it?

Comment: more question marks would really help....

Comment: You need to give more information. 1. How is the FASTQ format encapsulated? Is it a .FASTQ file? 2. What are you planning to use to write this?

Comment: 1) The example is the sample fastq format. I want to convert a character sequence in this format. However, I have no idea how to encode line 4. 2) If I understood properly the fastq format encoding scheme, I will try to write the code to generate such format using Java or C or C++..

Comment: Try asking at http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you only have the sequence and not the [quality (reliability) scores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phred_quality_score) of the sequence derivation, I **think** you don't have enough information to construct a FASTQ file.  (I am *not* a bioinformatics expert, however.)  Instead, you should probably keep using the [FASTA file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format), which contains only the sequence information.

Comment: Thanks.. It is quite useful for me.. I think you are correct, I need quality score to implement FASTQ format...

Comment: I do deal with both these formats on a regular basis at work, and yes, this is correct - you need a quality score for fastq, you should stick with fasta (which is probably what you have already).  In any case, the fastq format is, afaik, almost exclusively used for (relatively short) sequences resulting from deep-sequencing - I'm not sure why you'd even _want_ a chromosome sequence in that format.